# need help displaying every 10th year on x axis ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]Need help plotting every 10th year on the x axis.

```
temp_carbon %>%
  select(Year = year, Global = temp_anomaly, Land = land_anomaly, Ocean = ocean_anomaly) %>%
  gather(Region, Temp_anomaly, Global:Ocean) %>%
  drop_na() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Year, Temp_anomaly, col = Region)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), lty = 2) +
  geom_label(aes(x = 2005, y = -.08),label = "20th century mean", size = 4) +
  ylab("Temperature anomaly (degrees C)") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = function(x) exec(seq, !!!x), 
                     labels = function(x) x, 
                     limits = c(1880, 2018)) +
  ggtitle("Global, Land and Ocean Temperatures from 1880-2018")
```

The above is my current code and the picture above shows that the x axis is very messy and you cant see the years, how do i fix this?

Comment: How about removing the `scale_x_continuous(...)` line?

Comment: Take a look at `str(temp_carbon)`. I suspect `year` is a factor object. If so, try coercing to numeric with `temp_carbon %>% mutate(year=as.numeric(year)) %>% etc...`.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: So it would @H1 - good point!

Comment: im confused?, i dont understand

Comment: @Rachel Your earlier question asked how to display all of the years.  Perhaps you can be clearer on the output you want - e.g. do you want to label every 10th year? You won't get an attractive plot trying to include them all.

Comment: @ H 1, yes every 10th year would be great, how do i do that?

Comment: format your dates to Dates with `as.Date()`, then use `scale_x_date(date_breaks = "10 years")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is the output you want, read to see what I did along.

## Output

[image: ts_out]

Save your data as `df`

```r
df <- temp_carbon %>%
  select(Year = year, Global = temp_anomaly, Land = land_anomaly, Ocean = ocean_anomaly) %>%
  gather(Region, Temp_anomaly, Global:Ocean) %>%
  drop_na()
```

Then, use `lubridate` to convert it to proper date

```r
df$Year <- lubridate::ymd(df$Year, truncated = 2L)
# [1] "1880-01-01" "1881-01-01" "1882-01-01" "1883-01-01" "1884-01-01" "1885-01-01"
# This sets the month and date on Jan-01.
```

Prepare the base which shows every `thenth` `year` on `x-axis`. You can calculate every tenth year using `seq(min(year(df$Year)), max(year(df$Year)), by = 10)`

```r
base <- ggplot(df, aes(year(Year), Temp_anomaly, col = Region)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 7, vjust =0.5, margin=margin(5,0,0,0))) +
    scale_x_continuous(
        "Year", 
        labels = as.character(seq(min(year(df$Year)), max(year(df$Year)), by = 10)), 
        breaks = seq(min(year(df$Year)), max(year(df$Year)), by = 10), 
        expand=c(0,0)
    )
```

Finally your subsequent layers to the plot:

```r
base + geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), lty = 2) +
  geom_label(aes(x = 2005, y = -.08),label = "20th century mean", size = 4) +
  ylab("Temperature anomaly (degrees C)") + 
  ggtitle("Global, Land and Ocean Temperatures from 1880-2018")
```

Comment: I get the following errors: Error in year(df$Year) : could not find function "year" and Error: object 'base' not found

Comment: and how can the legend be tidy?, how can you make it readable?

Comment: add `library(lubridate)` at the top.

Comment: for the legend you can add  `+theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.direction="vertical", legend.spacing.x = unit(1.5, 'cm'))` at the end and customize it to your liking.